# Ruby script being a pain to run

Tags: ruby, bash

I have a .gz file in a folder called SequenceScripts.
I would like to unzip it and then run a ruby script on it which reformats it and puts it in a text file.
The ruby script is in the same folder.
I am doing this using Terminal on a mac.

The command I am using is:

```
gzcat tbb.fq.gz | ./reformat_sequence_data.rb > SLX-8691.ART03.txt
```

The response I am getting is: `env: ruby\r: No such file or directory`

The ruby script starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

There are no carriage returns in the script (checked with hidden characters visible).
When I run `ruby -v` from the command line I get: `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]`

I have no idea whats going on but I suspect the extra carriage return may have something to do with it but I dont know why its there. Can anyone help?

Comment: File should start with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` note the hash sign.

Comment: sorry typo the hash is actually there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you just run `dos2unix` or `sed` on it anyway:

```
dos2unix ./reformat_sequence_data.rb
sed -i 's|\r||' ./reformat_sequence_data.rb
```

If your file has `\r (0D)`, lines will show with this command:

```
hexdump -C < ./reformat_sequence_data.rb | grep -w 0d
```

Comment: Great that sorted it...kind of. Sooooooo annoying but now solved using the following: $ cat ./reformat_sequence_data.rb | col -b > ./reformat_sequence_data.rb

Comment: @user3632206 That's dangerous. Never open your file for input and output at the same time as that could truncate the file. Why didn't you just used `dos2unix` or `sed`?

Comment: Oh really? didnt have dos2unix on the mac and sed came up with errors so I followed the path of least resistance. Seems to work fine though. Sorry-wont do it again